# Class type issues

Tags: java, generics

I have a class named "toto" which I send to a function that does the following:

```
getData(toto);

public String getData(Class myClass) {
 javax.jdo.Query query = p.newQuery(myClass);
  List<myClass> list = (List<myClass>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
 for (myClass element : list) {
   Do something here
 }
}
```

The problem is that I get type compilation error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Joel

Comment: Of course, myClass is not a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a runtime variable as an "argument" to a generics construct (like `List<X>`). If you know something about the classes you'll pass in, then you can constrain that:

```
public String getData(Class<? extends Something> myClass) {
  // ...
  List<Something> list = (List<Something>) // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that the following way:

```
public <T> String getData(Class<T> myClass) {
    javax.jdo.Query query = p.newQuery(myClass);
    List<T> list = (List<T>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
    for (T element : list) {
       Do something here
    }
}
```

where, if you want to call any method other than `toString()` on `element`, you will need an interface/base type and change the definition to `<T extends YourInterface>`